# java Как правильно спрятать JPanel

Tags: java, swing, jpanel

Хочу по нажатию Кнопки спрятать одну панель, что позволит увидеть другую
У меня такой код

```
class MyWindow extends JFrame {
    public MyWindow (){
        setTitle("X/O");
        setBounds(300,300,400, 400);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon("icons.png");
        setIconImage(icon.getImage());

        JPanel mainPanel = new JPanel();                  //Создаю панели
        JPanel centerPanel = new JPanel();                                           
        JPanel bottomPanel = new JPanel();
        JPanel centerPanelWindowOne = new JPanel();
        JPanel centerPanelWindowTwo = new JPanel();

        mainPanel.setBackground(Color.blue);              //Цвета основных панелей
        centerPanel.setBackground(Color.white);
        bottomPanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(1,40));//Расположение остальных панелей
        centerPanel.add(centerPanelWindowOne);
        centerPanel.add(centerPanelWindowTwo);
        centerPanelWindowOne.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(400,40));
        centerPanelWindowTwo.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(400,40));

        add(mainPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);              //Указываю компановку
        add(bottomPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        add(centerPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        mainPanel.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        centerPanel.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        bottomPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout());
        centerPanelWindowOne.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        centerPanelWindowTwo.setLayout(new FlowLayout());

        JButton start = new JButton("Старт");
        bottomPanel.add(start);
        JButton exit = new JButton("Выход");
        bottomPanel.add(exit);

        exit.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                System.exit(0);
            }
        });

        start.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                centerPanel.setVisible(false);

            }
        });


        setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Итого, после нажатия кнопки Start хочу закрыть видимости centrePanel, и увидеть mainPanel, по моей логике я сначала создаю и показываю mainPanel, а затем centrePanel, и когда кнопкой я указываю видимость false для centrePanel, то должна отображаться mainPanel, но после кнопки start, в панель centrePanel закрывается, а там ничего, как правильно реализовать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Код скопирован отсюда: https://pacificsimplicity.ca/blog/simple-state-switching-java-example-using-jpanels-and-jbuttons

Кратко идея следующая:

- Надо создать еще одну JPanel и сделать её главной, добавляешь в JFrame
- Создаешь сколько тебе надо панелей (лучше в виде отдельных классов)
- Когда надо сменить JPanel - просто удаляешь все с главной панели, добавляешь нужную и перерисовываешь, лучше еще сделать revalidate()

  ```
  import javax.swing.*;
  import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
  import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

  enum ViewState {
      START_STATE, NEXT_STATE;
  }

  @SuppressWarnings("serial")
  class Panel2 extends JPanel {
      public Panel2() {
          JPanel  panel2 = new JPanel();
          JButton button = new JButton("sweet");
          button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
              @Override
              public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                  MyWindowTest.changeState(ViewState.START_STATE);
              }
          });
          panel2.add(button);
          this.add(panel2);
      }
  }

  @SuppressWarnings("serial")
  class Panel1 extends JPanel {
      public Panel1() {
          JPanel panel1 = new JPanel();
          JButton button = new JButton("my button");
          button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
              @Override
              public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                  MyWindowTest.changeState(ViewState.NEXT_STATE);
              }
          });
          panel1.add(button);
          this.add(panel1);
      }
  }

  public class MyWindowTest {
      private static ViewState viewState;
      private static JPanel mpanel;
      private static JPanel panel1;
      private static JPanel panel2;
      private static JFrame frame;

      public MyWindowTest() {

          frame = new JFrame();
          mpanel = new JPanel();
          panel1 = new Panel1();
          panel2 = new Panel2();

          // Sets default state
          changeState(ViewState.START_STATE);

          frame.setSize(100, 100);
          frame.add(mpanel);
          frame.setVisible(true);
      }

      public static void changeState(ViewState state) {
          viewState = state;
          System.out.println("change state: " + viewState);

          switch (state) {
              case START_STATE:
                  mpanel.removeAll();
                  mpanel.add(panel1);
                  mpanel.revalidate();
                  mpanel.repaint();
                  break;
              case NEXT_STATE:
                  mpanel.removeAll();
                  mpanel.add(panel2);
                  mpanel.revalidate();
                  mpanel.repaint();
                  break;
              default:
                  System.out.println("UNKNOWN STATE!");
                  break;
          }
      }

      public static void main(String[] args) {
          @SuppressWarnings("unused")
          MyWindowTest n = new MyWindowTest();

      }

  }
  ```

Comment: я перебрал данный код, и по сути он работает, хочу добавить свои изменения, и он работает не так как надо. Если вы выделите пару минут, а у Вас это больше не займет, я хочу показать Вам свой код и спросить пару вопросов, не хватает знаний, что бы реализовать свои хотелки, как это можно сделать что бы Вам было удобней? Если времени или желания нет, то просто проигнорте

Comment: @VladZherihov Я просто не представляю куда вы этот код добавите. Лучше просто создайте новый вопрос и всё. Если я смогу - я отвечу, хорошо? )

Comment: думал на почту архивом) могу и новый создать

Comment: @VladZherihov Если честно, лучше создайте новый, вдруг будут интересные мысли. Кому-то пригодиться может.

Comment: я только что выложил вопрос, обозвал: Не работает компановщик (setLayout) При возможности посмотрите пожалуйста) Описал как по мне подробно

Comment: @VladZherihov Я добавил там ответ.